# How to make each instance of a child class not require parent attributes (kinda?)

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    @classmethod
    def get_user(cls):
        return cls(input("Username: "))
 

class Budget(User):
    def __init__(self, monthtly_income):
        super().__init__(User.get_user())
        self.monthly_income = monthtly_income
        self.perc_lis = []
        self.category_obj_lis = []
        self.category_name_lis = []
        self.value_lis = []
...
# creates objects and adds them to a list
        for i in range(len(self.category_name_lis)):
            self.category_obj_lis.append("")
            self.category_obj_lis[i] = Category(self.category_name_lis[i], self.monthly_income)

...

class Category(Budget):
    def __init__(self, name, monthly_income):
        super().__init__(monthly_income)
        self.name = name
        self.perc = 0
        self.amt = 0
        self.left = 0
        self.max = 0
    
# defines the percentage for each category
    def get_perc(self):
        self.perc = float(input(f"{self.name}: "))
```

When I run this it asks for username 3 times after I have asked for the categories because I create each Category object in a loop. Username is asked for at the start of the code. I need the category class to be a child class because I need the monthly_income variable to use in code not posted. I am not very good at inheritance so i could easily be missing something obvious. Is there a way for each instance of Category to not ask for username and just use the one already asked in the beginning? I apologize if this is somewhat confusing but idk  where to go from here.

Comment: Taking a step back: it is a bad idea to mix input/output concerns with methods of your classes. Keep that outside of them, in the main program: read the input you need and then create instance(s) passing that user-provided information as argument.

Comment: Inheritence represents an **IS-A** relationship between the classes. A budget isn't a user, and a category isn't a budget. These shouldn't be subclasses.

Comment: @trincot This looks like a valid use case for a class method, though. I would agree if the call to `input` were inside `__init__`.

Comment: it is not good idea to use `input()` inside class - better first use `input()` to ask for name only once and later create `User(username)` and send this name to all created `Category(username)`